# Get rid of multiple white spaces in php or mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which takes user inputs; Recently, I have come across many user inputs with multiple white spaces.
Eg.
"My                  tests               are working            fine!"
Is there any way I can get rid of these white spaces at PHP level or MySQL level?

1. Clearly trim doesn't work here.
2. I was thinking of using Recursive function but not sure if there's an easy and fast way of doing this.

my code so far is as below:

```
function noWhiteSpaces($string) {
   if (!empty($string)) {
      $string = trim($string);
      $new_str = str_replace('&nbsp;&nbsp;', ' ', $string);
   } else {
      return false;
   }
   return $new_str;
}

echo noWhiteSpaces("My&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;tests&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;are working fine here&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;!");
```

Comment: Is the input actual whitespace (`\t`, `\n`, space, etc.) or stuff like `&nbsp;`? There's a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is actual whitespaces and you want to replace them with a single space, you could use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

```
$stripped = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $input);
```

`\s` means 'whitespace' character. `+` means one or more. So, this replaces every instance of one or more whitespace characters' in `$input` with a single space. See the [`preg_replace()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), and a nice [tutorial on regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

---

If you're not looking to replace real whitespace but rather stuff like `&nbsp;`, you could do the same, but not with `\s`. Use this instead:

```
$stripped = preg_replace('/(&nbsp;)+/', ' ', $input);
```

Note how the brackets enclose `&nbsp;`.

Comment: It's basically &nbsp; I have already tried preg_replace similar to what you are suggesting; that doesn't remove complete occurrences of white-spaces though. Thanks!

Comment: @phpfreak I've updated the answer. Next time, please be clear.